# Ruby reorganizing a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm trying to reorganize a hash so that a specific key is at the beginning, and another key is at the end. For example:

```
x = {:a => 123, :b => 456, :c => 789, :d => 123}
# returns => {:a=>123, :b=>456, :c=>789, :d=>123}
x.sort.reverse!
# returns => [[:d, 123], [:c, 789], [:b, 456], [:a, 123]]
```

How can I make the hash start with c and end with b after the sort?

EDIT: I need to order the hash because of when I do "x.each |key, object| do..." I need the hash to start with a particular key

Comment: Hashes in Ruby are not meant to be ordered, Arrays are.

Comment: @Rob Don't be bothered by the top two comments as they are wrong.

Comment: I need to order the hash because of when I do "x.each |key, object| do..." I need it it be in a particular order

Comment: @iamnotmaynard how could I do that with code?

Comment: I really see no sort-logic that would make c the start and b the end. Sort by what?

Comment: I'm not trying to sort them to start that way, I'm simply trying to reorganize the hash. Note the title of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on hashes order. Get the keys, order them, and loop the hash:

```
keys = x.keys
#sort how you need it
keys.each do |key|
  object = x[key]
  #do what you want
end
```

Comment: This seemed to work best with least amount of complications

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {:a => 123, :b => 456, :c => 789, :d => 123}

c, b = x.delete(:c), x.delete(:b)
Hash[[[:c, c], *x.sort.reverse, [:b, b]]]
# => {:c => 789, :d => 123, :a => 123, :b => 456}
```

or

```
c, b = x.delete(:c), x.delete(:b)
Hash[:c, c, *x.sort.reverse.flatten, :b, b]
# => {:c => 789, :d => 123, :a => 123, :b => 456}
```

Comment: Great answer but caused complications in the real world application (it's quite a bit more complicated than what was posted above). Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't seem complicated at all.  Reads like a book.

Answer (score -2):

Since Ruby 1.9 hashs keep their order (although this is ignored to the `==` operator). The problem is that most of these methods predate 1.9, they used to return an array. You can easily create a Hash from a pair-value Array this way:

```
x = {c: 1, d: 2, a: 3, b: 4}

x.sort.reverse
#=> [[:d, 2], [:c, 1], [:b, 4], [:a, 3]]

Hash[x.sort.reverse]
#=> {:d=>2, :c=>1, :b=>4, :a=>3}
```